# Finding the Kp and Ki expressions for PI controlled DC machine and what exactly does the bandwidth (wc) mean?

Tags: dc-motor, pid-controller

[image]

I found this method of tuning the PI control for a DC machine. It mentions that we can use the PI zero for pole cancellation of the plant.

**I cannot derive the expression shown for Kp and Ki in the image.** I tried to simplify the expression which I think is like this

[image]

**The author also mentions about *w*c which I cannot understand correctly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall objective here is to select values of \$\small K_p\$ and \$\small K_i\$ that will result in a 1st order closed loop TF with a selectable time constant, \$\small T\$.

Thus, the OLTF is \$\small G(s)\large =\frac{K_p s+K_i}{s(L_a s+R_a)}\$

If \$\small K_p=\omega_c L_a\$ and \$\small K_i =\omega_c R_a\$, then the OLTF becomes:
\$\small G(s)\large =\frac{\omega_c (L_a s+R_a)}{s(L_a s+R_a)}=\frac{\omega _c}{s}\$

and the CLTF is: \$\small G'(s)=\large\frac{\omega_c}{\omega_c +s}=\frac{1}{1+sT}\$, where \$ \small T\large = \frac{1}{\omega_c}\$

But note that a 1st order TF model of a DC motor is normally obtained from its mechanical parameters (inertia and viscous friction), rather than its electrical parameters.